# change 1234.0 to 1234 but leave 1.0234 using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I know this is a simple question, but I am trying to remove an extra decimal added to a file when its being converted (I can't change conversion) and currently using:

```
sed "s/\.0//g" $file -i
```

but whilst this works and changes `1234.0` to `1234`, it's being too good and also then changing `1.0234` to `1.234` which I can't have. I know I have to put further arguments into `s/` but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what the input looks like? Is `1234.0` at the end of a line? If not, how is it delimited?

Comment: its the only thing in the 'field' (its a csv file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the \b-boundary:

```
sed "s/\.0\b//g"

echo "but whilst this works and changes 1234.0 to 1234, it's being too good and also then changing 1.0234 to 1.234 which I can't have."  | sed "s/\.0\b//g"
but whilst this works and changes 1234 to 1234, it's being too good and also then changing 1.0234 to 1.234 which I can't have.
```

The $ will only work at end of line or end of input.

Comment: @Shruti: How does that work? You said it was a field in a CSV file. Unless it's the last field, it's going to be followed by a comma, and `$` won't match that.

Comment: I didn't use $, I tried with $ but I found same as your comment which is that my field is in middle of the file.  the \b worked however.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add an end-of-word boundary constraint

```
sed 's/\.0\>//' <<END
x 1234.0 y
m n 5.0
a 1.0234 b
END
```

```
x 1234 y
m n 5
a 1.0234 b
```

This is GNU specific. docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a `$` at the end of a regex string to tell it to look for matches at the end of the input.

```
sed 's/.0$//'
```

Comment: That works if the number is at the end of the line. It's not clear from the question whether that's the case.